# Is $x^{2\cdot 3^n}+x^{3^n}+1$ irreducible (mod 2)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

I'm new to the finite field theory, however after doing some trivial search on primitive polynomials, it seems that the  polynomials of the form 
$$x^{2\cdot3^n}+x^{3^n}+1 \pmod 2$$
are irreducible.

Is it possible to prove it? I think it isn't possible to apply the method of checking all of the generators ($\phi(2^{2\cdot 3^n}-1)$ ) to find the order of the zeros ([see this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/358182/primitive-polynomials)). What should I do?

It is easy to [show](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1830940/255648) that this polynomial is not primitive.

I checked the claim for $n=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ using [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor%5Bx%5E(2*3%5E6)%2Bx%5E(3%5E6)%2B1,modulus-%3E2%5D) and it is true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that $(x^{2\cdot 3^n}+x^{3^n}+1)(x^{3^n}-1)=x^{3^{n+1}}-1$, so your polynomial is the $3^{n+1}$st cyclotomic polynomial.

The $n$th cyclotomic polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_p$ exactly when $p$ is a primitive root mod $n$.

Since 2 is always a primitive root mod $3^n$, your polynomial is irreducible.